# Views and models as python package cannot be resolved

Tags: python, django, module

I'm fairly new to Django, and I try to get the hang of using modules for views and models. Strangely enough, the URls work fine.

- My app structure is

  ```
  templatetags/
  urls/
  views/
  models.py
  tests.py
  ```
- The views-dir has an `__init__.py`, and animals.py, containing one view.

  ```
  from myapp.models import Animal
  from django.shortcuts import render_to_response

  def overview(request):
      objects = Animal.objects.all()
      return render_to_response('myapp/animal_list.html', {'objects': objects})
  ```
- There's an animals.py in urls/, containing

  ```
  from myapp.views.animals import *
  urlpatterns = patterns('',
      url(r'^$', 'views.animals.overview', {}, 'myapp_animal_overview'),
  )
  ```

The result:
    Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Could not import views.animals. Error was: No module named animals

But it's there! Can anyone see where I go wrong here? My app consists of about 10 models, hence the need for splitting. 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Could you fix the formatting on your directory structure? Everything seems to have been crunched onto one line, which is most likely not what you intended.

Answer (score 1):

Well, generally, you don't need to import `myapp.views.animals`. The URL dispatcher imports the required view as necessary when the regex matches a requested URL, as per: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request.

Generally speaking, I would expect your urls.py to look something like:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url # for example ...

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', 'views.animals.overview'),
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You were right, I didn't need that extra import.

What did work, was

```
    urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.animals.overview'),
    )
```

I needed to specify the app where the views were. Problem solved!

Comment: This should be an edit to your original question or a comment to Lockjaw's answer. Since you asked the question, either one of those is a valid option.